# Use an if with a python str.find()

Tags: python

I am trying to parse the following string with Python : `At 11:00 am EST, no delay, 7 lane(s) open`. I need to read it to see if it contains the string `no delay`. I have used the following to parse it: `contents_of_tunnel.find("no delay")`.

This runs fine. But when I use it in an `if/else`, such as below:

```
>>> if contents_of_tunnel.find("no delay") == True:
...   print 1
... else:
...   print 0
... 
0
```

It comes out to zero. Why is this? I believe that the issue is with the first line, the one that goes like so: `>>> if contents_of_tunnel...`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `find` returns the index of the found string - not a boolean value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find(...)
  S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int

  Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
  such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
  arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

  Return -1 on failure.
```

The only way this will print 1 is if `contents_of_tunnel` starts with "no delay" because the index returned will be 0. -1 evaluates to `True`.

You should use:

```
if contents_of_tunnel.find("no delay") != -1:
```

or

```
if "no delay" in contents_of_tunnel:
```

or

```
try:
    index = contents_of_tunnel.index("no delay")
    # substring found
except ValueError:
    # substring not found
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
if 'no delay' in contents_of_tunnel: print 1
else: print 0
```

or just

```
print 1 if 'no delay' in contents_of_tunnel else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `contents_of_tunnel.find("no delay")` returns a number. Therefore, instead of using  a `== True`, use an `!= -1`. That way it will do what you had expected.

Comment: `is` tests for identity.